# How to load baskervaldx font in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to use the **baskervaldx** font in XeLaTeX; however it doesn't kern properly. With LaTeX it works as supposed.

What is the right way to load the Baskervaldx font?

With LaTeX, default install on Linux

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Hello} World

Top
\end{document}
```

[image: Baskervaldx -- LaTeX]

With XeTeX, otf files copied to ~/.fonts

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Baskervaldx}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Hello} World

Top
\end{document}
```

[image: Baskervaldx XeTeX]

Comment: The kerning is fine with `luatex`, but with `xetex` I get the same bad kerning you noticed.

Comment: Note that if things are properly set up, you shouldn't need to copy the files to another directory to use them - the system should know about the TeX directories (unless, of course, you don't wish it to).

Comment: This font is odd in other ways too.  Unless you want “poetry” to become “pœtry,” be sure to turn off the `rlig` feature.  Something like this should produce reasonable results, apart from the kerning problem in `xetex`: `\setmainfont{Baskervaldx}[Ligatures=NoRequired,Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=6}]`